# xpath select child and parent

Tags: php, xpath

I started using xPath today, and am still trying how to implement it correctly. I'm trying to make an xPath that finds other tables that reference them using the `COLUMN_FOREIGN_TABLE` field. Then the xPath should both return the `TABLE_NAME` and the `COLUMN_NAME`. I've seen some other questions about multiple values from xpath, but none of the answers really explained what was happening, and the problems weren't anything like this.

**The problem**
I can currently find the `TABLE_NAME` and the `COLUMN_NAME` seperate, but not combined. I need some way to have both, so I know what column from what table is referencing to it.

**What have I tried?**
Currently I have this code:

```php
$xml = file_get_contents('kingDbOverviewExpanded.xml'); // XML file location
$fullSchema = new SimpleXMLElement($xml); // Make XML element

$curr = $_GET['table']; // Gets table

$foundBacklinksTableName = $fullSchema->xpath('(//COLUMNS/COLUMN[COLUMN_FOREIGN_TABLE="' . $curr . '"])/../../TABLE_NAME'); // Gets the table names
$foundBacklinksColumnName = $fullSchema->xpath('(//COLUMNS/COLUMN[COLUMN_FOREIGN_TABLE="' . $curr . '"])/*[self::COLUMN_NAME]'); // Gets the column names
```

**XML Structure**
I currently have an XML file with the following structure:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TABLES>
  <TABLE>
    <TABLE_NAME>tabBtw</TABLE_NAME>
    <COLUMNS>
      <COLUMN>
        <COLUMN_NAME>BtwRksGID</COLUMN_NAME>
        <COLUMN_TYPE>integer</COLUMN_TYPE>
        <COLUMN_DEFAULT></COLUMN_DEFAULT>
        <COLUMN_INDEX_TYPE>FK</COLUMN_INDEX_TYPE>
        <COLUMN_FOREIGN_TABLE>tabRekeningSchema</COLUMN_FOREIGN_TABLE>
      </COLUMN>
    </COLUMNS>
  </TABLE>
</TABLES>
```

`COLUMN_FOREIGN_TABLE` can be empty, but also filled. The XML file is a file with 60k+ lines, and all `COLUMN_FOREIGN_TABLE`'s can be found back in some other tables `TABLE_NAME`

So what would I have to do to return both the values? And **why** should I do that that way? I'm still trying to learn xpath, and just the correct answer doesn't teach me anything, so I'd really appreciate it to know why things are happening.